# Finding numbers with largest multiplication result in a single O(n) pass through an array

Tags: java, time-complexity

Question: given an array, you need to find 3 elements inside the array that will give the biggest product of all when multiplied.

For example, given the following input:

`-4, 1, -8, 9, 6`

...the expected output is `-4`, `-8`, `9`, as `-4 * -8 * 9 == 288`.

you can assume that there are no nulls inside the array.
signature must be `public static int findTriplet(int[] a);`.

my code:

````
public static int findTriplet(int[] a) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE,
                maxLowby2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE, maxLowby1 = Integer.MIN_VALUE,
                secondMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE, minIndex = -1, maxIndex = -1, indexofLowby1 = -1;
        
        //we run a for loop to go over the array and collect all our needed information.
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            //first we find the smallest value
            if (min > a[i] && a[i] < 0) {
                min = a[i];
                minIndex = i;// we save the index so we can find other num that is negative and is different from this 1
            ////here we try to find the second smallest num in the array in such that it has to be a minus otherwise we wont be able to get a popsitive number(-1*-1=positive)
            //if the index is different and second Min is smaller then the value in a[i] and a[i] must be a negetive num;
            } else if (minIndex != i && secondMin > a[i] && a[i] < 0) {
                secondMin = a[i];
            }
            //
            if (max < a[i]) {
                max = a[i];
                maxIndex = i;
                //now we look for only positive numbers
                //here we need to find two other sumbers that are the biggest in the array but are different then each other.
            } else if (max > a[i] && a[i] >= 0 && maxLowby1 < a[i] && maxIndex != i) {

                maxLowby1 = a[i];
                indexofLowby1 = i;
                //here we find the last positive number that will be smaller the max and maxlowBy1
            } else if (a[i] >= 0 && indexofLowby1 != i)
                maxLowby2 = a[i];
        }
        // we creat the needed numbers and return the max value of them.
        int finalMax = max * maxLowby2 * maxLowby1;
        int secondMinus = max * min * secondMin;
        return Math.max(finalMax, secondMinus);

    } ```
````

Comment: You should at least hint on the language you're using when asking code specific questions. To me, this looks like PHP, but could be anything.

Comment: you should try running your code with a simple example and print step by step to see what happens. Or even better, use a debugger.
You can't ask people to debug your code for you. Although you are very welcome to post a question regarding a more specific matter that you don't understand and can't find an explanation online

Comment: `int[]` cannot contain nulls; it's an array of primitive `int`, which *always* have a value.

Comment: I've edited your question's title to be more descriptive of the specific problem. Please try to do this yourself in the future -- a good title summarizes the question well enough that someone can know what your problem is without needing to click through and read the body.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to keep track of three values it's pretty easy to avoid inner loops. Keep track of the positives and negatives separately. You'll only need to keep track of the two smallest negatives.

Compare each new number against the previously known values. By falling through you determine where to slide values down (in terms of absolute value) and insert the new one.

The special case of three values is treated distinctly. All three initial values are captured separately and only used in this instance. This does assume there are at least three values in the list.

```
n1 = n2 = p1 = p2 = p3 = 0;  // negatives / positives with largest abs()
m3 = m2 = m1 = int.minValue; // store for case when only three values

for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    m = a[i];
    if      (m > p3) { p1 = p2; p2 = p3; p3 = m; }
    else if (m > p2) { p1 = p2; p2 = m; }
    else if (m > p1) { p1 = m; }
    else if (m < n2) { n1 = n2; n2 = m; }
    else if (m < n1) { n1 = m; }

    switch (i)
    case 1 : m1 = m; break;
    case 2 : m2 = m; break;
    case 3 : m3 = m; break;
}

l = a.length;
if (l < 3)                  { v = 0; } // error?
else if (l == 3)            { v = m1 * m2 * m3; }
else if (n1 * n2 > p1 * p2) { v = n1 * n2 * p3; }
else                        { v = p1 * p2 * p3; }
return v;
```

Consider it to be pseudocode rather than proper Java.

https://www.online-python.com/Hreut5EWav

Below is essentially QuinncyJones's more compact logic but without the sort operation. And I reduced the number of variables involved aseell.:

```
n1 = n2 = 0; // two smallest negatives
m3 = m2 = m1 = int.minValue; // three largest values regardless of sign

for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    m = a[i];
    if      (m > m3) { m1 = m2; m2 = p3; m3 = m; }
    else if (m > m2) { m1 = m2; m2 = m; }
    else if (m > m1) { m1 = m; }

    if      (m < n2) { n1 = n2; n2 = m; }
    else if (m < n1) { n1 = m; }
}

return m3 < 0 || n1 == 0 || n1 * n2 < m1 * m2 ?
           m1 * m2 * m3 : n1 * n2 * m3;
```

https://www.online-python.com/FufUN9vAEp

Comment: If all the numbers are negative the product out come will be zero, because P1 will stay at zero;

Comment: Very well! Your solution takes the O(n) specification into account! The result is always the product of the 3 highest numbers or of the highest and the 2 lowest numbers! It doesn't matter if or how many negative numbers are present. You can simplify the return of the result even more. `return n1 * n2 < m1 * m2 ? m1 * m2 * m3 : n1 * n2 * m3;` I changed my answer to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LargestMultiple {
    private static void storeValues(
            int new_value,
            int[] values
    )
    {
        int i = -1;
        for (;i + 1 < values.length && new_value > values[i+1]; ++i){}
        if (i >= 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            {
                values[j] = values[j+1];
            }
            values[i] = new_value;
        }
    }

    public static int findTriplet(
            int[] a
    )
    {
        if (a.length == 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not enough values");
        }
        if (a.length <= 3)
        {
            int value = a[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < a.length; ++i)
            {
                value *= a[i];
            }
            return value;
        }

        int[] maximums = {0, 0, 0};
        int[] minimums = {0, 0};
        int[] negatives = {Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE};
        int num_positive = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] < 0)
            {
                storeValues(-a[i], minimums);
                storeValues(a[i], negatives);
            }
            else
            {
                storeValues(a[i], maximums);
                num_positive++;
            }
        }

        if (num_positive > 0)
        {
            return Math.max(
                    minimums[0] * minimums[1],
                    maximums[0] * maximums[1]
            ) * maximums[2];
        }
        else
        {
            return negatives[0] * negatives[1] * negatives[2];
        }
    }
    
    public static void test(final int[] values)
    {
        System.out.println(
                Arrays.toString(values)
                + " -> "
                + findTriplet(values)
        );
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        test(new int[]{1});
        test(new int[]{1, 2});
        test(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
        test(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
        test(new int[]{1, 2, -1, -2});
        test(new int[]{1, 2, -1});
        test(new int[]{1, 2, 3, -1});
        test(new int[]{1, 2, 3, -1, -4});
        test(new int[]{-1, -2, -3, -4});
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> [1] -> 1
> [1, 2] -> 2
> [1, 2, 3] -> 6
> [1, 2, 3, 4] -> 24
> [1, 2, -1, -2] -> 4
> [1, 2, -1] -> -2
> [1, 2, 3, -1] -> 6
> [1, 2, 3, -1, -4] -> 12
> [-1, -2, -3, -4] -> -6
> ```

*Note: Although `storeValues` is O(N) on the size of the array, it is always called from `findTriplet` with fixed-sized arrays then, from within that function, it will have a constant O(1) execution time.*

Answer (score 0):

The result is always the product of the 3 highest numbers or of the highest and the 2 lowest numbers. So the 2 lowest and the 3 highest numbers have to be found. An O(n) solution is therefore possible since this can be done in one loop pass.

```
public static int findTriplet(int[] a) {
    if(a.length < 3) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The array must have a length of at least 3!");
    int[] n = {Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE };
    for(int i : a) {
        // find two lowest
        if(i < n[0]) { n[1] = n[0]; n[0] = i; } 
        else if (i < n[1]) n[1] = i;
        // find three highest
        if(i > n[4]) { n[2] = n[3]; n[3] = n[4]; n[4] = i; }
        else if(i > n[3]) { n[2] = n[3]; n[3] = i; } 
        else if(i > n[2]) n[2] = i;
    }
    int case1 = n[0] * n[1];
    int case2 = n[2] * n[3];
    return n[4] * (case1 > case2 ? case1 : case2);
}
```